# maven plugin to create intellij files?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Is there a maven plugin to create intellij files?

I have a maven project for which I would like to generate intellij files so that I can import it into my IDE. I know there is an eclipse plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/

and I found a plugin for intellij as well however it says its retired, so I wasn't sure whether I should be using something else:  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/

I'm following a tutorial that wants me to use eclipse but I would like to use intellij. The pom.xml of the tutorial uses eclipse plugin with these configurations:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>
                                    org.apache.felix
                                </groupId>
                                <artifactId>
                                    maven-scr-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                <versionRange>
                                    [1.0.0,)
                                </versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>scr</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore/>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

If I try to open the project in intellij then none of the imports work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually open Maven projects directly from IntelliJ:

File → Import Project → "Import project from external model (Maven)"

Answer (score 1):

No need of any plugin to import maven project in itelliJ just file -> import project-> then select the pom.xml file of the project to be imported it will handle automatically all the dependencies.First time it will download the dependencies better have internet connection while importing first time